# How to copy html code from mail inbox?

Tags: html, vb.net, email

I have created an app that automatically logs in in hotmail.

The thing that I can't make it works is that after login app should save the mail's inbox html code in richtextbox1.text

My problem is that the html code that is saved is not from inbox page but from login page.

Code:

```
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.live.com")
        SMTP.EnableSsl = True
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymail@hotmail.com", "mypassword")
        SMTP.Port = "25"



        Dim Client As New WebClient()
        Dim Url As String
        Url = "https://dub128.mail.live.com/?fid=flinbox&paid=cmz5t5hGnc5BGUiAAjfeOiwA2&pad=2015-04-06T14%3A30%3A58.080Z&pat=2&pidx=2"

Dim Html As String = Client.DownloadString(New Uri(Url))
            Dim searhwiththis As String = RichTextBox1.Text
            RichTextBox1.Text = Html
```

Comment: You can't do that.  Instead, use IMAP.

Answer (score 2):

You're logging in via SMTP, then trying to grab the inbox with an HTTP request. This won't work - they're entirely separate protocols. Thus, your HTTP request gets redirected to the login form.

You'll need to script a submission of the login form to get a valid user session. Note, however, that most major webmail systems will detect and block attempts to automate logins (using things like captchas).

Better yet, use the correct protocol - IMAP - to download the emails in a standard manner rather than trying to parse the HTML for the user's inbox.